# With Meteor Deps.Dependency.hasDependents, how would one clean up memory, as mentioned in the docs?

Tags: memory, meteor

In the Meteor docs under Deps.Dependency.hasDependents, it says this:

*For reactive data sources that create many internal Dependencies, this function is useful to determine whether a particular Dependency is still tracking any dependency relationships or if it can be cleaned up to save memory.*

Can someone please provide an example of using dependency.hasDependents() to clean up memory?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get a good understanding on dependencies at all, so I recommend you to take close look on this tutorial made by Chris Mather: http://www.eventedmind.com/posts/meteor-build-a-reactive-data-source

In the simple following example you can ensure if the value is used somewhere in dependency (client code).

```
var title = 'My Headline';
var titleDeps = new Deps.Dependency;

var setTitle = function(s) {
  title = s;
  titleDeps.changed();
};

Template.HelloWorld.getTitle = function() {
  Deps.depend(titleDeps);
  return title;
};
```

So use {{getTitle}} somewhere in your Template and you got an dependency from the function Template.HelloWorld.getTitle to the var titleDeps.

So e.g. will print true

```
Template.HelloWorld.rendered = function() {
    console.log(titleDeps.hasDependents());
}
```

By removing Deps.depend(titleDeps); from Template.HelloWorld.getTitle you will see false.

In use case you could check against a db collection that was subscribed or something like that, so that you can unset the data to free up the cache.